# How to remove Apache service

Tags: apache2

We had Apache web server on Ubuntu 18.04 server. After our developers decided to use NGINX, we remove Apache and install NGINX.
I had remove Apache with:

- apt remove ...
- `systemctl stop apache2`
- `systemctl disable apache2`
- check if something exists in `/etc/systemd/apache*` (nothing was there).

It works as it should, but I noticed the next lines in the log:

```
-- Reboot --
Jun 11 09:33:28 ela1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jun 11 09:33:28 ela1 apache2[892]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
Jun 11 09:33:29 ela1 apache2[892]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 57: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
Jun 11 09:33:29 ela1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Any idea how to get rid of Apache?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to purge it with:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
```

Comment: Tnx. It works. Quick help :-)

Comment: @JanezKranjski if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by using the check mark on the left hand side of this answer.

Comment: Tnx for this. Done :-)

Comment: Is this answer working in 2023?  I checked the version apache2 -v, and it showed the version. why it's showing the version if I run the above command ..

Answer (score 2):

Usually if you want to remove package and config files your should use purge. The best way to remove package and its configuration files and dependencies system wide is to use `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`

Answer (score 0):

These commands will completely remove Apache2, all its configs and logs:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt purge apache2
sudo apt purge apache2-utils
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apache2
sudo rm -rf /var/log/apache2
```